# Pass login credentials to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I need to open file form share point file location. in order to do that, 
I need to pass user credentials.
The user has access to login into SharePoint location but when I pass that credentials through the URL it does not display the file

http://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxCRM/applicationdocument/DOC-006/123.jpg?user=xxxx@xxxx.com&password=xxxxx

Answer (score 1):

Please try one of these.    Note that I replaced your @ sign with %40 in the URL.

1. This has the username and password up front:
   http://username%40domain.com:passwordhere@xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxCRM/applicationdocument/DOC-006/123.jpg
2. This is your other one, with the @ sign just replaced with %40:
   http://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxCRM/applicationdocument/DOC-006/123.jpg?user=xxxx%40xxxx.com&password=xxxxx

Reference to where I obtained %40 from - http://www.asciitable.com/

Other More Recommended Options Though:

1. Implement Single Sign On
2. Have them just get the username/password prompt.
3. If you are opening from a program, using a REST or CSOM call to download the file and show it locally.  Easy to pass credentials in one of those ways.